# Form Action Process.php file not echoing results from mySQL DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Currently, I have an index.php file with a form and a text input from the user as well as a submit button.  When the submit button is pressed, the process.php file is supposed to get the data and echo it out.  However, it just sends me to a blank page and does not echo anything out.  I am well aware that I would need to style it the page, etc... But it just isn't echoing out at all.  I am already connected to the mySQL DB with another php script and have tested that and it works fine so I know I am connected.  What am i doing wrong?

index.php

```
    <form action="process.php" form method="post" id="myForm">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group">

                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                         <input aria-label="..." type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
                    </span>
                     <input aria-label="..." class="form-control" type="text" id="food1">
                </div>

            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

process.php

```
<?php
//Check whether the form has been submitted
if($_POST['submit'] == "Submit") 
{
    $varFood1 = $_POST['food1'];
    $sql = "SELECT menu.dish FROM menu WHERE menu.description LIKE '%varFood1%'"; // sql query
    $result = mysql_query($sql);


// Loop the recordset $result
// Each row will be made into an array ($row) using mysql_fetch_array
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

      echo "Items : {$row['dish']}\n";

     }
}
?>
```

Comment: **BLANK PAGES** ALWAYS means Syntax error in PHP. check you **php_error_log** or add `error_reporting(E_ALL);    ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your file.

Comment: Everything inside this `if($_POST['submit'] == "Submit"){...}` won't fire off, and for a few reasons.

Comment: Sorry I removed the tag.  I must have accidently clicked it.  I have even went as far as to remove the "if" statement and still a no go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `name` attribute not `id`. `<input aria-label="..." class="form-control" type="text" id="food1">` Try printting out the `POST` in the future.

```
<input aria-label="..." class="form-control" type="text" id="food1" name="food1">
```

Additional changes...

```
$varFood1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['food1']);
$sql = "SELECT menu.dish FROM menu WHERE menu.description LIKE '%$varFood1%'";
```

without escaping you open yourself to injections. You should consider switching driver to mysqli or PDO as well.

Comment: I have added the name="food1" as well but it still shows the blank page.

Comment: Any other ideas? @chris85

Comment: Did you output the `POST` values and verify they are there and what you expect? `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: The second `form` in your form element might  be causing it to submit incorrectly as well. `<form action="process.php" form`

Comment: After putting the print statement within my "if" statement at the bottom, I can verify that it is getting the data now.  Array ( [food1] => shrimp  [submit] => Submit ) is showing up.  Apparently something is messed up within the process.php file.  I removed the excess "form" in my html as well.

Comment: See where it hangs (or doesn't) by outputting something (using `echo` or `error_log`) throughout the process.

Comment: Apparently there is $result is nothing.  I have tried to echo it but it doesn't work.  I can echo $sql. The echo within with "while" loop doesn't work either.  Maybe there is something wrong with the query and that's why the while statement isn't running.

Comment: Yup that's your issue.. updating answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are checking for $_POST['submit'], which the process.php file does not see, because it does not exist in the POST array. Solution: give your submit button a name, instead of this: 
    `<input type="submit" value="Submit">`, 
which is what you have, do this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: I have added the name="submit" to the input but it still shows the blank page.